# Can't create a Stopwatch object in Lightswitch application in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, stopwatch

I am having trouble creating a simple Stopwatch object. Even though in other projects I am able to use it without any issue whatsoever, in my Lightswitch application this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch relojito = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
```

Produces nothing. I am using VS2012 and already checked all available objects on System.Diagnostics and Stopwatch is not there.

Am I doing something wrong? It's built in .NET 4.5 framework.

EDIT: It doesn't compile at all when I do this (type or namespace Stopwatch does not exist in System.Diagnostics error)

Comment: What do you mean by "produces nothing"?

Comment: what happens when you try to use `relojito`?

Comment: I added a bit more. Basically it doesn't compile since it doesn't find it in the Diagnostics namespace.

Comment: You are not referencing System assembly?

Comment: I am unable to reference System.Assembly and haven't done so in other projects where the object has been used.

Comment: What do you mean you are `unable to reference System Assembly`?  Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch* class doesn't exist in Silverlight 4 or higher (which is what LightSwitch is using), so you can't use it in a LightSwitch project.

On another note, you should be using *.NET 4.0* in any LightSwitch code, not *.NET 4.5*.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another object I could use that's as accurate as Stopwatch? I've looked around and timer doesn't seem like a good choice for very small measurements.